# Get psutil net_io_counters to match values in Network Connection Status

Tags: python, windows, network-programming, psutil

I'm using psutil to query the number of bytes sent and received over ethernet on Windows 10.

I can use `psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)` to get the values. However, when I parse the values I need, they are slightly higher than the byte count that I view in the system UI.

```
import psutil

network_stats = psutil.net_io_counters(pernic=True)['Ethernet']
bytes_sent = getattr(network_stats, 'bytes_sent')
bytes_recv = getattr(network_stats, 'bytes_recv')

print "Bytes Sent = {0} | Bytes Received = {1}".format(bytes_sent, bytes_recv)
```

My issue is, the number of bytes returned from this script is *always* higher than the byte count displayed in the Network Connections -> Ethernet Status UI. However, the difference is relatively small.

[image: Ethernet Status - Network Activity]

Is it possible to use psutil to get the sent/received values to match the Ethernet Status Activity in the screenshot above? And why are the values returned slightly different in the first place?

Comment: The [counts from psutil](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/release-5.2.2/psutil/_psutil_windows.c#L2285) include unicast, broadcast, and multicast bytes sent and received (i.e. `OutOctets` and `InOctets`). The connection status dialog only shows the unicast counts (i.e. `OutUcastOctets` and `InUcastOctets`). If you want this specific information, you'll need to use ctypes or a C extension to query the [`MIB_IF_ROW2`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa814491) info for the interface.